# How to get Git to convert CRLF files to LF, on Linux?

Tags: linux, git, line-endings, git-config

I'm trying to do something very simple: check out a repo that has CRLF endings (and no .gitattributes) file, and end up with native (LF) line endings. I don't even want to commit back.

I've read [Github's suggestion](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#platform-linux), and [Tim Clem's article](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/), but mostly they seem aimed at Windows developers.

I've tried this:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf=input
$ git clone https://github.com/DennisSchiefer/Project-OSRM-Web.git
```

But no - the file I care about, OSRM.Config.js, still has CRLF endings.

Trying `core.autocrlf=true` didn't help.

Even adding and committing a `.gitattributes` file (then `git rm --cached -r . && git reset --hard`) doesn't help.

I can't find any combination that will actually leave LF line endings on this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`core.autocrlf` will force git to process all *text* files.

If OSRM.Config.js is not processed, that means Git deems it binary.
See:

- "[How to determine if Git handles a file as binary or as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6119956/6309)"
- "[Why does Git treat this text file as a binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6855712/6309)"

Even with a `.gitattributes` with `*.js text`, that would still keep `crlf`.

But with `*.js eol=lf`, that would actually force the conversion.

See "[Can git's `.gitattributes` treat all files as binary except a few exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4264522/6309)".

Comment: Amongst other lines in my .gitattributes: `*.js text`

Comment: @SteveBennett `text` means `crlf diff`, like `binary` means `-crlf -diff` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4264522/6309) matbe try `*.js text lf diff`?

Comment: @SteveBennett or `*.js eol=lf`

Comment: @SteveBennett great. I have included my comments in the answer for more visibility.